# Compare two pandas dataframe for different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, time-complexity

Suppose I have two pandas DataFrame namely df1, df2

```
df1 = {name : [tom, jerry, jennifer, hafiz, kitty]}
df2 = {name : [tom, jerry, alex, hafiz, samdin, unnar]}
```

From this two datasets, I want to generate

```
good_boy = [tom, jerry] # present in both the datasets
bad_boy = [jenifer, hafiz, kitty] # present in df1 but not in df2
new_boy = [alex, samdin, unnar] # in df2 but not in df1
```

Actual dataset is very large with millions of rows, I tried doing iterative check, but it is damn slow. Is there any tric (parallel processing) already there in Pandas.
Please help me to solve this problem, my concent is time. Thank you

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='outer', indicator=True)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `DataFrame.join`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

```
good_boy = df1.join(df2, on = 'name', how = 'inner')[['name_left']].rename(columns = {'name_left' : 'name'})

bad_boy = df1[~df1['name'].isin(df2['name'].tolist())]

new_boy = df2[~df2['name'].isin(df1['name'].tolist())]
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by @QuangHoang in comments, the key here is `merge`. The `indicator=True` option asks for an additional `_merge` column indicating whether the row is present in one of the dataframes (and which one) or both:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['tom', 'jerry', 'jennifer', 'hafiz', 'kitty']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['tom', 'jerry', 'alex', 'hafiz', 'samdin', 'unnar']})

tmp = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='name', indicator=True)

good_boy = tmp.loc[tmp['_merge']=='both', 'name'].to_list()
bad_boy = tmp.loc[tmp['_merge']=='left_only', 'name'].to_list()
new_boy = tmp.loc[tmp['_merge']=='right_only', 'name'].to_list()
```